# Python Pandas Group by the same value and replace with the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Python Pandas with only two columns. The first one has repeated values like the following:

```
   A    B
   apple   0.5
   apple   0.8
   apple   1.4
   orange   0.4
   orange   1.1
   melon   0.3
   melon   0.1
   melon   0.9
   melon   1.2
```

What I want to do is to create a new dataframe with the mean of each value in the first dataframe. For example:

```
   A   B
   apple   0.9
   orange   0.75
   melon   0.625
```

The file has about 2.5m rows and I cannot do it in Excel. Any ideas how can this be done in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataframe, you can just `groupby` by 'A' and get the mean with:

```
g = df.groupby('A').mean()
```

This returns:

```
       B
A       
1  0.900
2  0.750
3  0.625
```

EDIT: if you're not familiar with pandas and you've got an external file, you can import it with:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(yourfile)
```

EDIT2:

```
g = df.groupby('A').mean()
```

works also with your edited dataframe of fruits:

```
            B
A            
apple   0.900
melon   0.625
orange  0.750
```

Comment: `df.groupby('A').mean().reset_index()` seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Tasos this is your desired output in your question, may you edit your question to clarify if you need something else?

Comment: The `groupby` should work no matter the order of your `ID`, it just groups equal entries and get the mean of their values.