# pandas replace column with mean for values

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas dataframe and want replace each value with the mean for it.

```
    ID    X     Y
    1     a     1
    2     a     2
    3     a     3
    4     b     2
    5     b     4
```

How do I replace Y values with mean Y for every unique X?

```
    ID    X     Y
    1     a     2
    2     a     2
    3     a     2
    4     b     3
    5     b     3
```

Comment: related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842728/python-pandas-group-by-the-same-value-and-replace-with-the-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Y'] = df.groupby('X')['Y'].transform('mean')
print (df)
   ID  X  Y
0   1  a  2
1   2  a  2
2   3  a  2
3   4  b  3
4   5  b  3
```

For new column in another `DataFrame` use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':['a','a','b']})
print (df1)
   X
0  a
1  a
2  b

df1['Y'] = df1['X'].map(df.drop_duplicates('X').set_index('X')['Y'])
print (df1)
   X  Y
0  a  2
1  a  2
2  b  3
```

Another solution:

```
df1['Y'] = df1['X'].map(df.groupby('X')['Y'].mean())
print (df1)
   X  Y
0  a  2
1  a  2
2  b  3
```

Comment: Thanks. If I have another similar dataframe without the Y column, how can I add another column for the X values using the calculated means?

Comment: Hard answer without data. But maybe need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414968/2901002) - `map` or `merge`